# When will cancellationtoken of C# source generator be canceled?

Tags: c#, roslyn

`Source generator` is a fantastic feature of Roslyn in this .NET 5 release,
by implementing `ISourceGenerator` you can get a result like that.

```cs
[Generator]
class OtherGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context){}
    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context){}
}
```

Here are the `GeneratorInitializationContext` and `GeneratorExecutionContext` which are owned `CancellationToken` to help us to make a executing decision.
My question is, when will the `CancellationToken` be **cancelled** ? When build process disrupted? Or how can I do if I want manually making CancellationToken be cancelled?

Thanks!

Comment: In general you shouldn't want to trip a cancellation token yourself if you don't own it; you can generate your own cancellation token and use `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource` to create a new token that will cancel on either of them being tripped.

Answer (score 3):

Your generator is also running in the Visual Studio IDE to provide real-time intellisense; if you make some changes to a file, we cancel the prior request to run the generator and start running generators again. So a well-behaved generator should observe the cancellation and abort the generation so you're not tying up extra CPU time.